# saltstack: Pass jinja variable from a salt state file to an included salt state

Tags: saltstack

I have the case where I have 3 salt states **A.sls**, **B.sls** and **C.sls** of which only one will be applied on a host. 
All 3 of them sets a jinja variable *x* to a specific value and then I want all 3 to call a mutual salt state **D.sls** which makes use of *x*.
How do I do this? I tried using `include: D.sls` but it is executed before I can set variable.

Answer (score 1):

The trick was not to use the Salt "include" directive, but the jinja include as shown in this answer: [Passing variables with include in salt-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743154/1877083)